# Combine two post-receive hooks

Tags: linux, git, shell, githooks, slack

How can I combine two post-receive hooks? The first one is a [git-slack integration](https://github.com/chriseldredge/git-slack-hook) and runs with the following loop:

```
while read line
do
  set -- $line
  notify $*
  RET=$?
done
```

and the second one is for my deployment and looks like this:

```
while read oldrev newrev refname line
do
   branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
   if [ "master" = "$branch" ]; then
     # some deployment commands
   elif [ "development" = "$branch" ]; then
     # some other deployment commands
   fi
done
```

No matter what branch I use for git, I would like to be able to send notifications to slack.

**Any tips on how to combine both loops?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has not been tested but should work:

```bash
while read oldrev newrev refname line
do
  set -- "$oldrev $newrev $refname $line"
  notify $*

  # Not sure the return value is needed since it isn't being used anywhere
  RET=$?

  branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
  if [ "master" = "$branch" ]; then
    # some deployment commands
  elif [ "development" = "$branch" ]; then
   # some other deployment commands
  fi
done
```

Hope this helps

Comment: perfect! thats what I love stackoverflow for :-). Would you mind telling me, what the set -- $... and notify $* means?